# Python CSV to XML converter

Tags: python, csv, xml, pandas, lxml

I'm creating an application that reads in data from a CSV file and creates an XML file using LXML. The below code works as expected. However, before I develop it further I would like to refactor it and make it more DRY. I will need to start creating the additional XML snippets for the other code types in the CSV file and I believe, in its current state, there is too much duplication.

I am attempting to learn Python while using a real user case, please can someone provide any guidance on how I could make the code more eloquent and more DRY. Do I need to be using classes and functions or is my approach OK for the type of file (XML) and creating?

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree as et
import uuid

df = pd.read_csv('assets.csv', sep=',')

root = et.Element('SignallingSchemeData', xmlns='boo')
timeframe = et.SubElement(root,'TimeFrame')
timeframe.attrib["fileUID"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
timeframe.attrib["name"] = str("timeframe 1")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['CODE'] == 'S1':
        equipment = et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')
        signalEquipment = et.SubElement(equipment, 'SignalEquipment')
        signalEquipment.attrib["fileUID"] = str(row["ID"])
        signalEquipment.attrib["name"] = str(row["DESC"])
        equipment = et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')
        equipmentSupportEquipment = et.SubElement(equipment, 'EquipmentSupportEquipment')
        equipmentSupportEquipment.attrib["fileUID"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        equipmentSupportReference = et.SubElement(signalEquipment, 'EquipmentSupportReference').text = equipmentSupportEquipment.attrib["fileUID"]
    else:
        equipment = et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')

source = et.SubElement(root, 'Source')
view = et.SubElement(root, 'View')
view.attrib["fileUID"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
view.attrib["name"] = str('Coordinates')


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    viewCoordinatesList = et.SubElement(view, 'ViewCoordinatesList')
    viewCoordinates = et.SubElement(viewCoordinatesList, 'ViewCoordinates')
    itemFileUID = et.SubElement(viewCoordinates, 'ItemFileUID')
    itemFileUID.attrib['fileUID'] = str(row['ID'])
    viewCoordinatePairLon = et.SubElement(viewCoordinates, 'ViewCoordinatePair', name = 'longittude')
    viewCoordinatePairLon.attrib['Value'] = str(row['Y'])
    viewCoordinatePairLat = et.SubElement(viewCoordinates, 'ViewCoordinatePair', name = 'latitude')
    viewCoordinatePairLat.attrib['Value'] = str(row['X'])
    viewCoordinatePairH = et.SubElement(viewCoordinates, 'ViewCoordinatePair', name = 'height')
    viewCoordinatePairH.attrib['Value'] = str(row['Z'])

et.ElementTree(root).write('test.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone = None)
```

assets.csv is as follows:

```
ID,CODE,ELR,TRID,DIR,MILEAGE,X,Y,Z,DESC,IMAGE
30734,S1,LEC1,1100,,008+0249 (9-1497),518169.12,185128.27,37.52,,Asset30734.jpg
31597,S10,LEC1,1100,,008+0286 (9-1460),518151.38,185157.1,36.7,IRJ at 8 miles and 0289 yards,Asset31597.jpg
31598,S10,LEC1,1100,,008+0286 (9-1460),518150.4,185156.11,36.7,IRJ at 8 miles and 0289 yards,Asset31598.jpg
31596,S10,LEC1,1100,,008+0287 (9-1458),518149.76,185157.14,36.7,IRJ at 8 miles and 0289 yards,Asset31596.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real issue with repeating yourself here is that you are iterating over your dataframe twice when you don't have to. Fortunately, the devs for `lxml` make the elements behave like lists, so you can create everything that you need to in one go, then just do `root.append(sub_element)` at the end like you would with a list.

Whenever you find yourself directly iterating over a pandas dataframe, that's usually a sign that it's not the correct data structure for the task. There are certainly exceptions, but I think using the `csv` module here might be a bit better of a fit. The reason being that you are technically iterating over the whole file with `pd.read_csv`, only to iterate again. `csv.reader` will allow you to iterate and process at the same time.

First, declare all of the trees you might need:

```py
import csv
from lxml import etree as et

# configure your elements here. lxml acts as a list,
# so make them their own trees until you are ready to merge
root = et.Element('SignallingSchemeData', xmlns='boo')
source = et.Element('Source')
view = et.Element('View')
```

Note that I haven't used the `SubElement` factory class yet. Since `Element` can be treated as a `list`, we can leave the linking of elements to `root` to the end of the script.

Moving forward:

```py
# you want this inserted first, so SubElement is 
# perfectly fine here
timeframe = et.SubElement(root,'TimeFrame')
timeframe.attrib["fileUID"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
# you don't need the str function call here, it's already a string
timeframe.attrib["name"] = "timeframe 1"

# open your file here
with open('assets.csv') as fh:
    # the separator by default is ','
    # so no need to specify it
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
```

Now, `csv.DictReader` allows you to keep the `row[key]` paradigm because it will create an `OrderedDict` for each row:

```py
with open('assets.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
    row = next(reader)

row
OrderedDict([('ID', '30734'), ('CODE', 'S1'), ('ELR', 'LEC1'), ('TRID', '1100'), ('DIR', ''), ('MILEAGE', '008+0249 (9-1497)'), ('X', '518169.12'), ('Y', '185128.27'), ('Z', '37.52'), ('DESC', ''), ('IMAGE', 'Asset30734.jpg')])

row['ID']
'30734'

row['CODE']
'S1'
```

This requires minimal changes from your original script. You can iterate over the reader just like before except the `index` doesn't have to be there anymore:

```py
with open('assets.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)

    for row in reader:
        # rest of loop
```

## Refactoring the loop

### Equipment

First, you can create a function to handle everything that's happening in the `if` block. This makes the core of the loop more readable, as well as logically separates functions of the code. Overall, the core logic is good. Your variable names are descriptive, if a little lengthy, with the only change really being formatting:

```py
def add_equipment(root, row):
    '''Add equipment elements and supporting child elements to root'''
    equipment = et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')

    # I'm grouping blocks of code/variables that group together
    signal_equipment = et.SubElement(equipment, 'SignalEquipment')
    signal_equipment.attrib["fileUID"] = row["ID"]
    signal_equipment.attrib["name"] = row["DESC"]

    # The names have been changed to snake_case with lowercased
    # letters, as is the naming conventions of variables and functions
    # in python (but not classes)
    equipment = et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')
    eq_support = et.SubElement(equipment, 'EquipmentSupportEquipment')
    eq_support.attrib["fileUID"] = str(uuid.uuid4())

    reference = et.SubElement(signal_equipment, 'EquipmentSupportReference').text = eq_support.attrib["fileUID"]
```

I don't need to return anything because `root` is being modified in-place by these operations.

Now, the first portion of your loop looks like this:

```py
with open('assets.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)

    for row in reader:
        if row['CODE'] == 'S1':
            # now all of this code sits
            # in a function, and it's much easier to tell what's
            # going on
            add_equipment(root, row)
        else:
            equipment = et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')
```

### View

The `view` can be cleaned up in pretty much the same manner. Again, I don't really see anything egregious other than just some logical grouping and formatting. Your code and logical flow looks good, it's clear and easy to read

```py
def add_view(view, row):
    '''Add supporting child elements to view. Pass in row for value extraction'''
    view_list = et.SubElement(view, 'ViewCoordinatesList')

    view_coords = et.SubElement(view_list, 'ViewCoordinates')

    item_file_uid = et.SubElement(view_coords, 'ItemFileUID')
    item_file_uid.attrib['fileUID'] = row['ID']

    longitude = et.SubElement(view_coords, 'ViewCoordinatePair', name='longittude')
    longitude.attrib['Value'] = row['Y']

    latitude = et.SubElement(view_coords, 'ViewCoordinatePair', name='latitude')
    latitude.attrib['Value'] = row['X']

    height = et.SubElement(view_coords, 'ViewCoordinatePair', name='height')
    height.attrib['Value'] = row['Z']
```

You don't need the `str` to wrap `row['X']` anymore because `csv.DictReader` doesn't infer datatypes, everything is a string.

The loop as a whole now looks like this:

```py
with open('assets.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)

    for row in reader:
        if row['CODE'] == 'S1':
            # refactor to a function here that
            # adds to root and takes row as an argument
            add_equipment(root, row)
        else:
            equipment = et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')

        # add the rest of your loop in a function here to
        # deal with the view tree, again, take row as an argument
        add_view(view, row)
```

Now, your loop can just be read as a loop, and the logic inside the if blocks is abstracted into functions.

## Constructing your tree

Now, to get everything in order, it's just a call to `root.append`:

```py
root.append(source)
root.append(view)
```

And everything is in order with one pass over the csv file. Your last line can remain perfectly intact:

```py
et.ElementTree(root).write('test.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone=None)
```

## Timing Results

### Original Script

```py
python -m timeit 'import file'
10 loops, best of 3: 0.118 usec per loop
```

### Refactored Script

```py
python -m timeit 'import file2'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0809 usec per loop
```